A generalization of center of a ring
Let $R$ be a ring. The center of $R$ denoted by $Z(R)$ is defined as $Z(R)=\lbrace x \in R | xy=yx~\forall y\in R\rbrace$. Are there any generalizations of center of ring? I know one structure but I am not sure exactly how it defined, it is something like this $Q(R)=\lbrace x \in R | xy=y'x~\text{for some } y'\in R\rbrace$

This may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer .

What about Normaliser of an element?

There is a generalization (possibly more than one) for any kind of algebra, but that is perhaps beyond the scope of this post?

No it is not beyond the scope.  Please feel free to write. @amrsa

(I have some misgivings about how you've defined it but) is that even an additive subgroup of the ring?

It is something called Quasi center of a ring defined as Rx=xR. Also there are some special rings called left duo rings and (right duo rings) defined as every left ideal is two sides and (similarly). They may have some connection to this.
